# Why should I keep my soul, anyway?

Tags: sunless-sea

The Devil may hang around Georgia occasionally and strike deals with passing fiddle players when he's running behind, but selling your soul in Sunless Sea takes a bit more effort. There are at least two places I know of where you can part with your soul: the Wistful Deviless at Mount Palmerston in the north (where you can part with your soul to further your acquaintance with the Deviless), and the Empire of Hands in the east (where your soul can be sold for cash on the barrelhead in several different ways).

That said, is there a problem with selling my soul? If I sell it to the Empire of Hands, will I regret not having it later for some reason? I.e., missing a soul locks out an option, or I'll have an even better opportunity to sell it elsewhere. Does it affect the legacy of future captains, or the ability to find a sweetheart or proposition an officer? (In the browser game Fallen London, "some of [those who sell their souls] become mumbling, dead-eyed husks," according to the lore.)

Comment: I don't know... selling your soul does not seem like a healthy thing to do.

Comment: That's *precisely* why I'm tempted to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. No downside. There used to be a situation where it made a specific action impossible, but they patched that, so it was a glitch rather than intentional.

as of 23/Mar, there is no downside.

Comment: Are the Wistful Deviless and the Empire of Hands the only two places to sell it? I'm also worried about missing out on something even better.

Comment: Yup. I updated http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/Menaces:_Soulless with all the possible interactions for you, so you can browse at your leisure. There's been talk on the forum of it doing more later, but for now, feel free to go around with no soul.